# Can Javascript inside HTML <object> tag detect it's <object> parent?

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom

```
<html>
  <body>
  <object data="mysvg.svg"></object>
  </bocy>
</html>
```

For the example HTML, if the material loading into the `<object>` tag, is a pure SVG document with a root tag `<svg>`, and that SVG has Javascript scripting in it, can said SVG hosted Javascript detect its parentNode(s) upstream, so the script can determine whether it's running within an object. Or not.

Maybe this is a design characteristic of `<object>` and perhaps `<iframe>`, where the hosted Javascript cannot see the DOM tree upstream of where it's contained.

Thank you.

Comment: somehow, I doubt it. while JS can dig from parent->child for iframes and external content, it'd be a security risk to allow child->parent.e.g. consider loading an svg from an external site from an email in a webmail system.w ould you want that external site providing the svg be able to dig back up your tree and rummage around your inbox?

Comment: Probably not, Marc.  But, my objective is to be able for the svg to realize it's running in an object, and be able to re-size the height-width of it, since IE11 isn't smart enough to do that unaided.  Firefox seems to know about the underlying dimensions of an enclosesd <svg>, I haven't tested other browsers like Chrome or Safari.  Thanks for your answer, and your analogy.

Comment: might not be able to rummage back up and see if it's inside an object, or an iframe, or whatever, but it SHOULD be able to detect the height/width of its own container, without ever knowing exactly what that container really is.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that Marc?  What's the Javascript call approach, to what, how, etc.?  This doesn't seem obvious.  What I'd like to do is force a "change" on the container height/width, based on the SVG and its scripting resizing itself.  Not just read it.

Comment: you can use css media queries to target specific SVG elements under different viewport sizes.

Comment: again, you probably couldn't change the container's size since that'd allow this theoretical outside svg to take over the user's window by just setting width/height to 100% of the window. but js should be able to access the dom of the svg, get the top-level node's height/width, and go from there.

Comment: Gotcha, Marc.  The challenge I have is, the SVG root element height and width varies, and can adjust after it's loaded also.  The enclosing page HTML has no idea what size it is beforehand.  Fortunately, Firefox and Safari behave nicely, IE doesn't, and haven't tested any others.  So...there's somewhat of a workaround.  Maybe I could try Javascript from the host page/tag, to go inquire within, then resize--if that's not blocked either.